# How to verify the output of a conditional statement (learning JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

What am I missing?

In this murder mystery there are:

four rooms: the ballroom, gallery, billiards room, and dining room,
four weapons: poison, a trophy, a pool stick, and a knife,
and four suspects: Mr. Parkes, Ms. Van Cleve, Mrs. Sparr, and Mr. Kalehoff.
We also know that each weapon corresponds to a particular room, so...

- the poison belongs to the ballroom,
- the trophy belongs to the gallery,
- the pool stick belongs to the billiards room,
- and the knife belongs to the dining room.

And we know that each suspect was located in a specific room at the time of the murder.

- Mr. Parkes was located in the dining room.
- Ms. Van Cleve was located in the gallery.
- Mrs. Sparr was located in the billiards room.
- Mr. Kalehoff was located in the ballroom.

To help solve this mystery, write a combination of conditional statements that:

1. sets the value of weapon based on the room and
2. sets the value of solved to true if the value of room matches the
   suspect's room

Afterwards, print the following to the console if the mystery was solved:

__________ did it in the __________ with the __________!

So I entered the following

```
// change the value of `room` and `suspect` to test your code
var room = "dining room";
var suspect = "Mr. Parkes";

 var weapon = "knife";
  var solved = false;

if (room == "gallery" && suspect == "Ms. Van Cleve") {
solved = true;
weapon == "trophy";

} else if (room == "dining room" && suspect == "Mr. Parkes") {
    solved = true;
weapon == "knife";

} else if (room == "billiards room" && suspect == "Mrs. Sparr") {
    solved = true;
weapon == "pool stick";

} else  { room == "ballroom";
        suspect == "Mr. Kalehoff";
        weapon == "poison";
        solved = true;

}

 if (solved) {
console.log(suspect +  "did it in the" + room + "with the" + weapon +"!");
 }
```

But keep getting

Try Again

**What Went Well**

- Your code should have a variable room
- Your code should have a variable suspect
- Your code should have a variable weapon
- Your code should have a variable solved
- Your code should include a conditional statement
- The variable suspect should use one of the provided values
- The variable weapon should be based on the room

**What Went Wrong**

- Verify that your conditional statements are producing the correct output (REMEMBER: Test your code with different values)

Comment: Your console.log comes right? are you sure you have to use blanks in the result log? like `console.log( suspect + "did it in the" + room + "with the" + weapon + 
 "!");`

Comment: How you are getting `Try Again` ?

Comment: `room == "dining room" && suspect == "Mr. Parkes"` is wrong, you are assuming that those variables will hold those values, but clearly the test runner you are using is trying with different values

Comment: _"(REMEMBER: Test your code with different values)"_ You can't just hardcode 1 answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't completing both steps of solving the mystery.

> To help solve this mystery, write a combination of conditional
>   statements that:
>
> 1) sets the value of weapon based on the room and sets the value of
>   solved to true if the value of room matches the suspect's room

You should have an if statement like

```
if (room == "dining room")
{
    //set weapon
}    
else if (room == "ballroom")
{
    //set weapon
}
else if (room == "billiards room")
{
    //set weapon
}
else if (room == "gallery")
{
    //set weapon
}
```

Also, your conditional statement in your else-if is incorrect. It should be || not &&

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what are the valid rooms for each suspect, and the valid weapons for each room.

```
var weapons = {
   'dining room': 'knife',
   'ballroom': 'poison',
   'gallery': 'trophy',
   'billiards room': 'pool stick'
};

var rooms = {
   'Mr. Parkes': 'dining room',
   'Ms. Van Cleve': 'gallery',
   'Mrs. Sparr': 'billiards room',
   'Mr. Kalehoff': 'ballroom'
};

var suspect = "Mr. Parkes";
var solved = false;

var room = rooms[suspect];
var weapon = weapons[room];

if(room !== undefined && weapon !== undefined) {
   solved = true;
}

if(solved === true) {
   console.log(suspect + " did it in the " + room + " with the " + weapon + "!");
}
```

Comment: This look like a very legit (and informative!) answer but it still gives the same error

- Verify that your conditional statements are producing the correct output (REMEMBER: Test your code with different values)

Answer (score 0):

```
var room = "dining room";
var suspect = "Mr. Parkes";

var weapon = "";
var solved = false;

if (room === "ballroom") {
weapon = "poison"; solved = suspect === "Mr. Kalehoff";
} else if (room === "gallery") {
weapon = "trophy"; solved = suspect === "Ms. Van Cleve";
 } else if (room === "billiards room") {
weapon = "pool stick"; solved = suspect === "Mrs. Sparr";
} else {
weapon = "knife"; solved = suspect === "Mr. Parkes";
 }

if (solved) {
console.log(`${suspect} did it in the ${room} with the ${weapon}!`);
 }
```